# MRSS - Display poster/background image on audio-only feed

Tags: rss

Not sure if this is possible, but I need to display a poster/background image in an MRSS feed where I am playing audio only, not sure if this can be done. As at the moment, when the player accesses this feed, it plays the audio, but with a black background. I am hoping to add an image there, but not sure what element to use. I have checked the MRSS specs here http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss, but it doesn't look like they've been updated for a while and I cannot find how to add such a background image.

```
<item>
         <title>My Title</title>
         <link></link>
         <description>My Description</description>
         <guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>
         <media:category>All</media:category>
         <media:category>Music</media:category>
         <media:content url="http://linktoaudiofile.mp3 language="en-us" medium="audio" isDefault="true">
            <media:title type="plain">Title</media:title>
            <media:description type="html">Description</media:description>
            <media:thumbnail url="icon_large.png" />
            <media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">Author</media:credit>
            <media:copyright url="coprightURL" />
         </media:content>
      </item>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Happy to also understand if this can be done a different way, such as using a player with the  element instead?